# resize datagrid on browser resize

Tags: apache-flex

I have a datagrid that occupies 100% of browser screen. I want the grid to automatically resize when the browser is resized to small or full screen. pls help...

-vivek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the grid's size to 100%x100% or set top/right/bottom/left to some value and make sure that the SWF itself is full size. Note that all parent elements above the grid are required to have a relative size as well.

Otherwise you can listen to `StageEvent.RESIZE`.